# The package “BluetoothSDK.pkg” is untrusted

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, command-line-tool, xcode4.6.3

I have just reset my OS to 10.7 (latest my mac can go), and downloaded Xcode. Whenever I try to install the older iOS simulators I get an error `The package “iPhoneSimulator… .pkg” is untrusted.` And when installing command line tools, I get the error `The package “BluetoothSDK.pkg” is untrusted.` How can I install these?   BTW I got Xcode 4.6

Comment: I'm having this problem as well on `Mac OS X 10.7.5` using `Xcode 4.6.1`. If you found a solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem installing the Command Line Tools. Then I found a binary at https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ that worked. Look for Command Line Tools and search the version regarding your OS version. A certification issue also appears, but we can go on and trust the binary.